# Complex power using phasors derivation

Tags: power

I am trying to come up with a bit of a derivation for \$ P = \frac{1}{2}V_mI_m\cos(\theta) \$ and \$ Q = \frac{1}{2}V_mI_m\sin(\theta) \$, but using phasors (because I can visualise it better).

I know the following (mostly from another question that I asked):
$$
\text{Let } v(t) = V_m\cos(\omega t) \text{ and } i(t) = I_m\cos(\omega t + \theta)\\
p(t) = v(t)i(t)\\
p(t) = V_m\cos(\omega t)I_m\cos(\omega t + \theta)\\
p(t) = \frac{V_mI_m}{2}(\cos(\theta) + \cos(2\omega t + \theta))
$$
Then from the above it is easy to see that the average value is:
$$
\bar{p}(t) = \frac{V_mI_m}{2}\cos(\theta)
$$

Now this is not at all with phasors, I tried to get a similar thing going with phasors...

Here is my (failed) attempt.

If I assume I have some vector **I** for the current and some vector **V** for the voltage such that
$$
\textbf{I} = I_m\angle \theta\\
\textbf{V} = V_m \angle 0 = V_m
$$

Now from my understanding of Real Power, the real power is the component of the current, **I**, that goes in the direction of the voltage, multiplied by the voltage, **V**.

So the component of **I** that goes in the direction of **V** is
$$
\textbf{I}_v = |\textbf{I}|\cos(\theta) \cdot \frac{\textbf{V}}{|\textbf{V}|}\\
\textbf{I}_v = |\textbf{I}|\cos(\theta)\angle 0
$$

So now we have the component of **I** that goes in the direction of **V**.

Now I thought I'd just literally multiply that by **V**
$$
\textbf{P} = \textbf{V}\textbf{I}_v\\
\textbf{P} = |V_m||I_m| \cos(\theta) \angle 0
$$

Now bringing that back into the time domain
$$
p(t) = \left(V_mI_m\cos(\theta)\right)cos(\omega t)
$$

I'm pretty sure that this is just wrong...  However, I can't work out where it doesn't make sense!

Answer (score 2):

The error is in that you're using the amplitude instead of the RMS value:

$$P = V_{RMS} \cdot I_{RMS} \cdot cos(\theta) $$

but for sinusoidal signals, \$V_{RMS}=\dfrac{V_{M}}{\sqrt{2}}\$ and \$I_{RMS}=\dfrac{I_{M}}{\sqrt{2}}\$ so multiplying:

$$P = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} V_{M} \cdot I_{M} \cdot cos(\theta)

 = \frac{1}{2} V_{M} \cdot I_{M} \cdot cos(\theta) =\\

 = \sqrt{\frac{1}{T} \int_T [p(t)]^2 \:\mathrm{d}t}


$$

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  To get the RMS values, I believe that  you're supposed to take the average value of the power.  My issue is that above I have 'found' (from the phasor method) that the real power is \$p(t) = \left(V_mI_m\cos(\theta)\right)cos(\omega t)\$, so I thought that I could then use the average value integral to get \$P = V_{RMS} I_{RMS} \cos(\theta)\$; however, this does not seem to work.

Comment: @user968243 Because p(t) and P are two different animals: p(t) is again a sinusoidal signal, so you have to take the average of the square of p(t) and then apply the square root.

Answer (score 0):

Point is that by multiplying phasors (input of two complex numbers) you will have product that is also a phasor (another complex number), and this one have same frequency as two input ones, so clearly you can't use phasors to calculate active and/or reactive power in that fashion. By multiplying phasors you can only easily calculate response of passive linear network on AC input signal. Read more:

http://www.cirvirlab.com/index.php/electric/99-phasor-ac-signal-multiplication-and-division.html